# How can I retrieve current TCP congestion window size from the kernel? Any command or simple script?

Tags: tcp, congestion-control

Is there any command or script to retrieve the current TCP congestion window of a tcp connection. So suppose some communication is going on over tcp through the network interface (eg. eth0), now is there any way to dynamically (periodically) retrieve the tcp congestion window?(in Linux platform)

Comment: Note that the TCP congestion window is maintained per TCP connection , not per network interface. Though, on TCP connection setup, the congestion windows is set to the maximum segment size, which is the MTU of the network interface minus the protocol headers.

Comment: What platform? And is the "I" an actual human being? Or a program?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any command or script to retrieve the current TCP congestion window of a network interface?

No, because there isn't any such thing. Network interfaces don't have congestion windows. Connections do.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try tcpprobe. By dynamic loading [tcpprobe](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610012009/http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tcpprobe), you can get the congestion window size.